# How can i implement Flutter flip animation for book reading app

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flip

I am currently working on Ebook reader app and looking to implement the book page flip effect in flutter.

UI I want to achieve

[image]

I have tried Using the [flip_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flip_widget) but it does not have feature to render from file extension such as epub or pdf.

I have also tried using [bookFx](https://pub.dev/packages/bookfx) package but the package has support for images only. So, I also tried fetching pdf pages and converting to images but it did not work too.

There are other packages too but the problem with most of the packages are either not maintained or does not have support for flip animation

Comment: You can   check  [How to create page curl effect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57802420/10157127)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh as you can see the page curl effect has support for flutter text widget and image. I want to implement this in pdf or and EPUB

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh     please were u able to achieve it in the book app ?

Comment: Nope, I've not implemented this on my app until now.