# I want flutter page curl effect using PageView.builder,

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, page-curl

other animation packages for curl effect doesn't work fine after adding more images.
I used [How to create page curl effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57802420/how-to-create-page-curl-effect)
this one but it fluctuates when we are adding more images to it.
I want to use Transform widget inside PageView.builder to work like that.
[image]

I tried many packages for that but I didn't succeed.